# Is GroupLayout in java is heavy or not?

Tags: java, swing, layout

Am interested to know is group layout is heavy while compared with the combination of two or more layouts like Border, flow, Grid and box.

Comment: `GroupLayout` really wasn't meant for "hand" coding, it was designed to provide support to GUI/form editors.  The question depends on the meaning of "heavy".  The time taken to layout a form will ultimately depend on the complexity of the layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GroupLayout uses two types of arrangements -- sequential and parallel, combined with hierarchical composition.

With sequential arrangement, the components are simply placed one after another, just like BoxLayout or FlowLayout would do along one axis. The position of each component is defined as being relative to the preceding component.
The second way places the components in parallel—on top of each other in the same space. They can be baseline-, top-, or bottom-aligned along the vertical axis. Along the horizontal axis, they can be left-, right-, or center-aligned if the components are not all the same size.
Usually, components placed in parallel in one dimension are in a sequence in the other, so that they do not overlap.

What makes these two arrangements powerful is that they can be nested hierarchically. For this purpose GroupLayout defines layout groups. A group is either sequential or parallel and may contain components, other groups, and gaps.

The size of a sequential group is the sum of the sizes of the contained elements, and the size of a parallel group corresponds to the size of the largest element (although, depending on the elements and where the baseline lands, the size of a baseline-aligned group may be a bit larger than the largest element).

Defining a layout means defining how the components should be grouped by combining the sequential and parallel arrangements.

Answer (score 1):

This is too abstract, it depends on the exact combination of elements in both cases.

Try and compre the two cases by profiling them, there are several good profiling tools for java like [Yourkit](http://yourkit.com/) or [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/).